# Vertical Centre Line

Tags: r, ggplot2, broom

For the following example, let I want to add a vertical centre line at value 1 of the x-axis. I tried by `geom_estci`(http://ggepi.lukewjohnston.com/reference/geom_estci.html), but my R doesn't find `geom_estci` function. I have both library ggplot2 and broom installed. I tried to install ggepi library. But it doesn't work for R version 3.6.1. How can I add a vertical centre line at x=1 for the following example?

```
  d=data.frame(drink=c("coffee","tea","water"), mean=c(3,6,2), lower=c(2.6,5.6,1.8), 
  upper=c(3.5,6.3,2.8))
  ggplot() + 
  geom_errorbarh(data=d, mapping=aes(y=drink, x=upper, xmin=upper, xmax=lower), height=0.2, size=1, 
  color="blue") + 
  geom_point(data=d, mapping=aes(y=drink, x=mean), size=4, shape=21, fill="white")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `geom_vline(xintercept = 1)`.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_errorbarh(data=d, mapping=aes(y=drink, x=upper, xmin=upper, xmax=lower), height=0.2, size=1, 
                 color="blue") + 
  geom_point(data=d, mapping=aes(y=drink, x=mean), size=4, shape=21, fill="white") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1)
```